# Friedrich's second inequality for functions with zero average

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities, sobolev-spaces, differential-forms

Friedrich's second inequality (or Maxwell Estimates or Gaffney’s inequality in the literature) is referred as follows: for all $\mathbf{u} \in H^1(\Omega)^2$ satisfying either $\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{u}=0$ or $\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$ on $\partial \Omega$ where $\Omega$ is a simply connected Lipchitz domain, then
$$
\|\mathbf{u}\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C_1\left(\|\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|\nabla \times \mathbf{u}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\right).
$$

My question is that if the boundary condition is satisfied, we only know the mean value of $\mathbf{u}$ is $0$ or simply replace the LHS with $\|\mathbf{u}-\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}\mathbf{u}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$. Does the inequality above hold?

Or at least, particularly, if $\mathbf{u}$ is divergence-free, do we have
$$
\|\mathbf{u}-\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}\mathbf{u}\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C_1\|\nabla \times \mathbf{u}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}.
$$

Thank you in advance!